# How to get store link with Bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

How on installation step I can get store url? Because store hash is not the thing I really need I guess, as then I can't access is somehow by link.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the bigcommerce api, you can get the [store information:  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/store_information](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/store_information) according the documentation

the api response give you:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => [your-store-identifier]
    [domain] => [youstore-domain-name].mybigcommerce.com
    [name] => test
    [address] => 
    [phone] => 
    [admin_email] => test@domain.com
    [order_email] => test@domain.com
    [language] => en
    [currency] => USD
    [currency_symbol] => $
    [decimal_separator] => .
    [thousands_separator] => ,
    [decimal_places] => 2
    [currency_symbol_location] => left
    [weight_units] => LBS
    [dimension_units] => Inches
    [dimension_decimal_places] => 2
    [dimension_decimal_token] => .
    [dimension_thousands_token] => ,
    [plan_name] => Professional Application Developer Store
    [logo] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_price_entered_with_tax] => 
    [active_comparison_modules] => Array
        (
        )

)
```